# EasyAccordion jquery plugin resume after click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-accordion

"easyAccordion" jquery plugin stop its movement after clicking on a tab and never resume after that.but i need it , should i implement it myself or this plugin has it embeded? i couldn't find such option.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. Are you asking about the features of a plugin?

Comment: yes,that is my question.

Comment: My advice is to install it and check it out. Play with the different options. I don't entirely understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Search for this part of code:

```
    jQuery(this).find('dt').not('active').click(function(){     
        jQuery(this).activateSlide();
        clearTimeout(timerInstance.value);
    });
```

Replace it with:

```
    jQuery(this).find('dt').not('active').click(function(){     
        jQuery(this).activateSlide();
        clearTimeout(timerInstance.value);

        timerInstance.value = setTimeout(function(){
            accordianInstance.rotateSlides(interval, timerInstance);
        }, interval);

    });
```

Greetings,

Michel